# rails: deploy workers for delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job, resque

Is there any good practices about setting up a queue to work with [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) in rails ?

For more precisions: I intend to ping some web hooks with my rails api. If using delayed_jobs, the PseudoCode could look like

```
get :ping do 
  present ping: :pong #grape style

  # Bad, synchronous idea: 
  MyAwesomeTracker.send(event: "ping") # thi will wait for the server answer before it goes on

  #Better: put it in a queue using delay_job:
  MyAwesomeTracker.delay.send(event: "ping") # this will go to the queue
end
```

Now wether I use job_delay or resque, I'm able to send events into the queue, which is great.

**The actual question:** Is there any good practices for deploying workers whenever I deploy my api ? 
What about worker failures ? Is there any environnement where a worker can be restarted after a crash/failure ?

I've seen a worker can be launched by running `rake some_command`, but what I'm wondering is how to set up an environment where a simple `cap production deploy` would both set up the api application, and some workers that listen to the queue.

Thanks in advance !